# How to get compiler warnings for floating asyncs

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, eslint

I'm using `ts` and `tsx` in visual studio 2019. I've enabled `eslint` in options, but still am not getting any warnings in visual studio.

I see that VS is complaining:

> Warning   internal-error  (ESLint) Failed to load plugin
> 'no-floating-promise' declared in 'Scripts.eslintrc': Cannot find
> module 'eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise' Require stack:
> C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ESLint_*placeholder*_.js  D:\Projects\General\General
> (tsconfig or jsconfig project)

But all my googling could not find me an answer what am i supposed to do about this

Here's an abridged version of my eslintrc

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // Allows support of JSX, but use of React plugin is required to support React semantics
    }
  },
  // @typescript-eslint/parser is specified as a command line argument
  "plugins": [
    "node",
    "promise",
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "amd": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true, // This enables ES6 global variables AND ES6 syntax
    "worker": true
  },
  "rules": {
    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint:recommended https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js (all errors set to warning)
    "constructor-super": 1,
    "for-direction": 1,
    "getter-return": 1,
    "no-async-promise-executor": 1,
    "no-case-declarations": 1,
    "no-class-assign": 1,
    "no-compare-neg-zero": 1,
    ..............
    "require-atomic-updates": 1,
    "require-yield": 1,
    "use-isnan": 1,
    "valid-typeof": 1,

    // Other rules
    "default-param-last": 1,
    "eqeqeq": 1,

    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint-plugin-react:recommended https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended (all errors set to warn)
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
   .........
    "react/require-render-return": 1,

    // Some additional React rules
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1
    "no-floating-promises": 1
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "*.ts", "*.tsx" ],
      "rules": {
        // The below are all rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint:recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/eslint-recommended.ts (all errors set to warn)
        "getter-return": 0, //Checked by Typescript - ts(2378)
       ........
        "no-redeclare": 0, // This is already checked by Typescript.

        // The below is some, but not all, of the rules from @typescript-eslint/recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended.json (all errors set to warn)
        "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": 1,
        "camelcase": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": 1,
     .........
        "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": 1,
        "no-var": 1,
        "prefer-const": 1,
        "prefer-rest-params": 1,
        "prefer-spread": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please advise

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to just install the plugin? `npm i -D eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise`
- and then restart VS.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes I tried now installing and restarting. but nothing changed. nothing is marked or flagged in VS or in the cmd window. Please advise.

Comment: Check  [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise#usage) You should include `"no-floating-promise"` in the plugins and then include `"no-floating-promise/no-floating-promise": 2` in the rules section.

Answer (score 0):

Change the no-floating-promises rule with @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises.